# Как отследить изменение атрибута класса python?

Tags: python

Каким образом можно отследить изменение атрибута класса и при нужном значении запускать функцию?

```
Пример кода

сlass Vehicle(object):
 
    def __init__(self, color, doors):
        self.color = color
        self.doors = doors

    def print():
        if color == 'green':
              print('color green')
```

пример поведения

```
car = Vehicle("blue", 5)
#ничего не печатается

car.color = 'green'
#выводиться color green
```

Comment: объявите в классе сеттер

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, color, doors):
        self._color = color
        self.doors = doors

    def _print(self):
        if self._color == 'green':
            print('color green')
        elif self._color == 'red':
            print('color red')
              
    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter    
    def color(self, value):
        self._color = value
        self._print()
  
              
car = Vehicle("blue", 5)
car.color = 'green'
car.color = 'red'
```

Comment: @мнетолькоспросить что не так ?